# How to initialize vector in template class constructor with dependent element types

Tags: c++, templates, types, vector, constructor

This is my code for a template class and its constructor. I am not able to initialize the vector whose elements are complex template types.

```
template <class Key, class Obj>
class HashTable{
    typedef int T;  
    typedef pair<const Key, Obj> Entry;
    typedef list<Entry> Bucket;
    typedef vector<Bucket> BktArray;
private:
    T n, nbuckets;
    BktArray a;
public:
    HashTable(T capacity = 199){
        n = 0;
        nbuckets = capacity;
        Bucket b();
        a = vector<Bucket>(capacity, b);
    }
};
```

I am getting "no matching function for call" in the line:

```
a = vector<Bucket>(capacity, b);
```

I would like to initialize the vector to contain "capacity" elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bucket b();` declares a *function* called `b` which returns a `Bucket` instance. Not what you want here (hence the mismatching type). `b` is also unnecessary, the `vector` constructor without it does the correct thing (= it default-constructs its elements).

More generally, you should absolutely use initialiser lists here. Thus, rewrite your code as follows:

```
HashTable(T capacity = 199)
    : n(), nbuckets(capacity), a(vector<Bucket>(capacity))
{ }
```

Also, having `T` as a type alias for `int` is quite misleading, I don’t recommend it. The standard type name in this context would be `size_type`, but it should be an *unsigned* type, not (`signed`) `int`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. However, I don't quite understand it. This code works fine:
"    pair<int, int> p(1, 2);
    vector<pair<int, int> > v(10, p);"
Shouldn't then my code also work in a similar logic?

Comment: @PulkitYadav Logic unfortunately has nothing to do with it. It’s an ambiguity in the language that resulted from grafting new features onto a language (C) which didn’t previously support them, and trying to stay backwards compatible. As a consequence we are left with arbitrary rules to break the ambiguity. This is one of them. This is known as the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).